# Java application startup suddenly extremely slow

Tags: java, windows

Since yesterday I experience a very strange issue. I'm a dev so I already spent 12 hours solving this issue with no success prior to asking this question.

My configuration: Windows 10 Pro 64b, 1803. Latest Java 8.

Start up time of every Java application is 100x larger than the previous day. For example, "Configure Java", i.e. javacpl.exe takes 3 minutes to start, Pycharm takes 20 minutes start etc. Once started, everything works nominally. Once closed, the start up time issue repeats.

I have already reinstalled Java, even tried Java 11 to no improvement. I reinstalled all applications affected, no improvement.

During the startup, the application runs high on CPU (1 thread 100%), with no disk or network activity.

I do not think I changed anything in previous days that would affect Java. Only thing that stands out is Cumulative Windows Update 2018-11 that installed. I believe there must be other people experiencing this.

I would like to fix this without the need to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Sounds like a typical windows problem. Anti-virus configuration change? Windows firewall?

Comment: Try setting up a barebone VM with nothing but openjdk installed and run your application in there. Experiencing the same issue? Probably something with the application. Can't reproduce? Probably something with your pc setup.

Comment: And if you have it activated your pc should have made a system recovery point before updating so you can rollback to before the update and delay it for up to 25(?) days should that really turn out to be the problem

Comment: All applications work fine on another PC with the same Windows, Java and application versions. Restore is not an option, even though activated, it only shows a single restore point from today.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help, I ended up reinstalling Windows which solved the problem.